# Xcode - Multiple POST parameters

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa

I got this code for sending a POST request to a PHP page:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://example.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *variableToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=my real data"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [variableToSend length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[variableToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// Create url connection and fire request
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSLog(@"Response: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

And that works fine. However, what if i want more variables? Using the above, i can do this in PHP: $_POST['test'] and it will print out "my real data". But what if i wanted another POST parameter? Maybe something like $_POST["another"]? How would i go about doing that.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Do you know what the POST body content should be to achieve your goal?

Comment: Your question is about `@"test=my real data"];`. Have you researched what it means and how to add multiple parameters to a post request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send data from ints, floats, strings, etc...  you can do it this way:
For example, you want to send name and lastname

```
    NSString *sendData = @"name=";
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];

    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&lastname="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lastname]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/userName"]];

    [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    //Here you send your data
    [request setHTTPBody:[sendData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    else
    {
       //The response is in data
    }
```

In php, I return always an array with json_encode, and then, I use NSDictionary to read it in ios

Comment: thanks mate. Accepted this answer since it provides a little more info, and also goes a little into what should be returned from PHP. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The line you are interested in is this one:

```
NSString *variableToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=my real data"];
```

In HTTP requests like this you separate parameters with `&` like so:

```
NSString *variableToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"field1=value&field2=othervalue"];
```